# Must one include all "file.o" files where there is "#include "file.h" "

Tags: c++, installation, g++, makefile, cross-compiling

I have  massive cross compilation of omxplayer whcih I am trying to debug. The file is downloaded from [here](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer). Unfortunately there are over 5000 files so I can not upload the directory tree. Here is the make command that gets issued:

> /path/to/cross/compiler/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/mnt/root -Wall -L/mnt/root/lib -L/mnt/root/lib -L/mnt/root/usr/lib -L/mnt/root/usr/lib/omxplayer -L/mnt/root/opt/vc/lib -L/mnt/root/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L./ -ldbus-1 -lc -lWFC -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lbcm_host -lopenmaxil -lfreetype -lz -Lffmpeg_compiled/usr/local/lib/ -o omxplayer.bin linux/XMemUtils.o utils/log.o DynamicDll.o utils/PCMRemap.o utils/RegExp.o OMXSubtitleTagSami.o OMXOverlayCodecText.o BitstreamConverter.o linux/RBP.o OMXThread.o OMXReader.o OMXStreamInfo.o OMXAudioCodecOMX.o OMXCore.o OMXVideo.o OMXAudio.o OMXClock.o File.o OMXPlayerVideo.o OMXPlayerAudio.o OMXPlayerSubtitles.o SubtitleRenderer.o Unicode.o Srt.o KeyConfig.o OMXControl.o Keyboard.o omxplayer.o -lvchiq_arm -lvcos -lrt -lpthread -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -lpcre `./arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config --libs dbus-1` -lrt

But then I get the following errors:

```
/path/to/cross/compiler/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.51, needed by /mnt/root/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpostproc.so.52, may conflict with libavutil.so.52
BitstreamConverter.o: In function `DllAvUtilBase::av_frame_move_ref(AVFrame*, AVFrame*)':
BitstreamConverter.cpp:(.text._ZN13DllAvUtilBase17av_frame_move_refEP7AVFrameS1_[_ZN13DllAvUtilBase17av_frame_move_refEP7AVFrameS1_]+0x8): undefined reference to `av_frame_move_ref'
BitstreamConverter.o: In function `DllAvUtilBase::av_frame_unref(AVFrame*)':
BitstreamConverter.cpp:(.text._ZN13DllAvUtilBase14av_frame_unrefEP7AVFrame[_ZN13DllAvUtilBase14av_frame_unrefEP7AVFrame]+0x4): undefined reference to `av_frame_unref'
BitstreamConverter.o: In function `DllAvUtilBase::av_frame_alloc()':
BitstreamConverter.cpp:(.text._ZN13DllAvUtilBase14av_frame_allocEv[_ZN13DllAvUtilBase14av_frame_allocEv]+0x0): undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc'
BitstreamConverter.o: In function `DllAvUtilBase::av_frame_free(AVFrame**)':
BitstreamConverter.cpp:(.text._ZN13DllAvUtilBase13av_frame_freeEPP7AVFrame[_ZN13DllAvUtilBase13av_frame_freeEPP7AVFrame]+0x4): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [omxplayer.bin] Error 1
```

I traced the `av_frame_unref` function and the others to `frame.h` which is in both `ffmpeg_compiled/usr/local/include/libavutil/frame.h` and `ffmpeg/libavutil/frame.h`. Normally I would link to the `.so` library with `-lframe` or `-Lffmpeg/libavutil/ -lframe`, however, this is not a shared library (`.so` file) but an object file (`.o` file). I am pretty sure I do not have to link these manually, that's what the make file is for. Anyone shed some light on what is going on. Also, I will include my Makefile below (I also have a Makefile.include showing the cross compile options, I can post that as well if necessary)

**Makefile:**

```
SRC=linux/XMemUtils.cpp \
        utils/log.cpp \
        DynamicDll.cpp \
        utils/PCMRemap.cpp \
        utils/RegExp.cpp \
        OMXSubtitleTagSami.cpp \
        OMXOverlayCodecText.cpp \
        BitstreamConverter.cpp \
        linux/RBP.cpp \
        OMXThread.cpp \
        OMXReader.cpp \
        OMXStreamInfo.cpp \
        OMXAudioCodecOMX.cpp \
        OMXCore.cpp \
        OMXVideo.cpp \
        OMXAudio.cpp \
        OMXClock.cpp \
        File.cpp \
        OMXPlayerVideo.cpp \
        OMXPlayerAudio.cpp \
        OMXPlayerSubtitles.cpp \
        SubtitleRenderer.cpp \
        Unicode.cpp \
        Srt.cpp \
        KeyConfig.cpp \
        OMXControl.cpp \
        Keyboard.cpp \
        omxplayer.cpp \

OBJS+=$(filter %.o,$(SRC:.cpp=.o))

all: omxplayer.bin

%.o: %.cpp
    @rm -f $@ 
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@ -Wno-deprecated-declarations

version:
    bash gen_version.sh > version.h 

omxplayer.bin: version $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o omxplayer.bin $(OBJS) -lvchiq_arm -lvcos -lrt -lpthread -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -lpcre `./arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config --libs dbus-1` -lrt
    #arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-strip omxplayer.bin

clean:
    for i in $(OBJS); do (if test -e "$$i"; then ( rm $$i ); fi ); done
    @rm -f omxplayer.old.log omxplayer.log
    @rm -f omxplayer.bin
    @rm -rf $(DIST)
    @rm -f omxplayer-dist.tar.gz

ffmpeg:
    @rm -rf ffmpeg
    make -f Makefile.ffmpeg
    make -f Makefile.ffmpeg install

dist: omxplayer.bin
    mkdir -p $(DIST)/usr/lib/omxplayer
    mkdir -p $(DIST)/usr/bin
    mkdir -p $(DIST)/usr/share/doc
    cp omxplayer omxplayer.bin $(DIST)/usr/bin
    cp COPYING $(DIST)/usr/share/doc/
    cp README.md $(DIST)/usr/share/doc/README
    cp -a ffmpeg_compiled/usr/local/lib/*.so* $(DIST)/usr/lib/omxplayer/
    tar -czf omxplayer-dist.tar.gz $(DIST)
```

Comment: Which `frame.cpp` defines e.g. `av_frame_move_ref`?

Comment: @Beta both are identical, and both have the header file which has the signature for `av_frame_move_ref` but only `ffmpeg/libavutil/` has `frame.o` and `frame.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to pull in the function definition from the `.o` files at compile time. I found this article very helpful in explaining the theory behind this:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking/

For more information on linking and compiling, I also highly recommend this book: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/index.html

Comment: That link gives one possible reason why this is happening, but the examples given where so trivial that it does not help me.

Comment: I'm going around and adding `foo/bar.o` statements all over the place, is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The article explains, among other things, that compilation and linking are two separate processes. If you want to know which object file contains definitions for which symbols (ie. functions in this case), you can use `nm x.o`, as is described in the article. If you just want to tell the linker to look in a specific directory for a library, you can use the `-L` switch. Note that the compiler will pass on switches to the linker. With gcc and linux, `ld` is the linker command; so, you can see a list of switches here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld

Comment: The problem was that it didn't occur to me that I had to manually link the object files because I just assumed the person who wrote the makefile (thanks a lot you jerk!) would have the decency to not leave out crucial components.

Answer (score 0):

I went around and mule-headedly started adding `foo/bar.o` instructions after `g++`, luckily I only had to put two of these: `ffmpeg/libavutil/frame.o` and `ffmpeg/libavutil/buffer.o`. I finally got omxplayer to install. Note, if Linux has taught me anything it's that just because something *compiles* doesn't mean that it will *work*.

In hindsight, this makes perfect sense and I should have done it before, problem is that most websites either deal with insanely trivial situations, like `g++ -o foo.o bar.o` or insanely complex cases where you are redefining `pkg-config` to be cross compile capable and then setting up a dozen flags before even using that. I find these large Makefiles are always difficult to deal with for novice programmers.

Comment: Did you `make ffmpeg`? I wonder if the command `make -f Makefile.ffmpeg install` was ever performed. The compile line includes `-lavutil` which suggests that it expects to find `libavutil` (either `.so` or `.a`) in some standard library location, and the fact that `libavutil` is a subfolder of `ffmpeg` is also suggestive. For what it's worth, the header files (`.h`) are really not relevant to linking. Although many people use the convention that a `.h` file corresponds to a `.o` file, absolutely nothing enforces that convention.

Comment: @rici I did issue the command `make ffmpeg` and it compiled, and I can tell u that u can't issue it twice. I did **not** issue the command `make -f Makefile.ffmpeg install`, but I'm guessing the latter calls the former (just confirmed it).

Comment: @rici you have to understand that this was a cross compile, and that Makefile is **not** designed for this (despite whatever the programmer may say). I had to make so many changes that I almost gave up, and I am not even talking about using the cross compiler, I am talking about glaring omissions.

Comment: you can issue make commands twice but make is normally clever enough to not actually do anything the second time unless a source has changed. It's possible that the make install step failed, though, and that won't be checked by make. With a well-written makefile (and some documentation), things like make triggering make install shouldn't be necessary. I know `make` seems like complete black magic, and also that many people write bad makefiles (cut-and-paste is a common disease) but it's a really cool tool once you figure it out. Anyway, you seem to have solved your problem...

Comment: ... but I would have suggested checking to see if ffmpeg/libavutil.{so,a} exists, or ffmpeg/libavutil/libavutil{so,a}, and adding a `-L` as appropriate. Anyway, the comment on header files stands.

Comment: @rici there is a libavutil.so in both ffmpeg/ and ffmpeg_compiled.

Comment: The compiler line has `-Lffmpeg_compiled/usr/local/lib/`, slightly hidden among the options. So it should be in `ffmpeg_compiled/user/local/lib`. If it's there, the link step should work -- but that's making the assumption that it includes all the ffmpeg functions (and also that the library you find is correct for the cross-compile.)